# Google Maps stealing focus when map is below the fold

Tags: google-maps, focus

I have a website which is using Google Maps to display the location of a property. This map is located below the fold on the website.

In IE8, Firefox, Safari etc this is working fine, but in IE7 (at the moment, specifically on Windows XP, can't really test on Vista/7 at the moment) the Maps seem to steal the focus and scrolls the page down.

I am unable to find any documentation which might indicate this is a known issue, or there is a workaround for it, but it would be really nice if I could stop it :) Or, if not, I might have to hack around it...

Comment: Does your page validate? I believe if the browser is rendering in quirks mode Maps is not guaranteed to be accurate... The browser needs to be in standards-compliance mode. Are you missing a <!DOCTYPE >?

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually figured out what the issue was - and it wasn't actually related to Google Maps..

We had a jQuery UI Datepicker hooked up to a separate element, which wasn't actually on that page, but when the init method was being run it was jumping down specifically on that call.

Unusual, no idea why, but thats what it was... so I guess this question should be closed as invalid...